# problemas com string e split C#

Tags: c#, array, string

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
string str = "1 2 3 4 5"; //string para separar
string[] ArrayValor = str.Split(" ");
//nesse caso o array seria {"1","2","3","4","5"}
```

mas queria algo mais genérico, por exemplo, se o usuário colocasse "1-2-3-4-5", também queria que o array retornasse {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
resumindo, quero apenas os números de uma string, não importando o que estiver entre eles.

Comment: Use a função [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) - `str.Split(" ")`

Comment: mais eu precisava descobrir o spliter, tipo se a string fosse "1-2-3-4-5" atribuir ao spliter o "-"

Comment: Sua pergunta não ta muito claro quanto ao que você quer, tente deixá-la mais clara que será mais fácil encontrar alguma ajuda. :)

Comment: Agora, o que poderá haver entre os números? Serão sempre os mesmos caractéres? Poderão ser diferentes caractéres  na mesma string?

Comment: poderão ser caracteres diferentes, tentarei deixar a pergunta mais clara

Comment: Você quer separar por qualquer caractér que esteja entre os números? Por exemplo, se a string for `"2+5-4a8s4"`, você quer obter um array somente com os números?

Comment: não, na verdade a string terá apenas números (alguns com vírgula) e o spliter (que não tenho controle, as vezes é um espaço, as vezes é um traço e por ai vai)

Comment: Eu fechei porque a resposta aceita não condiz com o que a pergunta está pedindo. Se a pergunta ficar mais clara é possível reabrir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode fazer um split usando [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx), dessa maneira você pode considerar um padrão para separar a string.

Vamos considerar que nosso padrão para separar seja tudo que não seja um número exceto pontos (que podem estar entre os números)

- `^\d` considero tudo que não seja um número
- `&\.` e aqui adiciono o ponto como "exceção"

Exemplo:

```
var regexp = new Regex(@"[^\d&\.]");
var valor = "4.5+8-8d5+5.4";
var arrNumeros = regexp.Split(valor);
//arrNumeros = ["4.5", "8, "8", "5", "5.4"];
```

Veja o [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R41Dv6) funcionando

Comment: opa, obrigado, é disso mesmo que eu precisava.

Answer (score 5):

Tenta fazer algo onde vc pega o primeiro char do spliter, mas lembrando que você sempre terá que ter os mesmos caracteres em toda a string se não, não funciona!

Obs.: A string deve seguir um padrão sempre com a primeira letra seguida do "spliter" e manter o mesmo char do spliter para toda a string. Dá para melhorar bastante o código com validações, ai vai do seu gosto! Lembrando que isso é só uma ideia, e não algo concreto!

```
    string str = "1 2 3 4 5";
    string spliterType = str.Substring(1, 1);
   var strSplited = str.Split(Convert.ToChar(spliterType));
```

Comment: vlw, aqui funcionou direitinho